# jQuery - .text() function with multiple rows in SQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, sql

I am writing my very first webapp in ASP.NET.
and jQuery .text() and .html() functions giving me unwanted results.
Everything works if there are not multiple rows inside SQL text field.

I have global javascript variable inside File.aspx with SQL content. 
Variable with SQL content have break line in it made in SQLyog text editor.

External file.js with wanted function is reaching for global variable inside File.aspx.

**SQL:**

[image]

**File.aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var testTitle = "<%=descriptionTitle%>";
    var testText = "<%=descriptionText%>";
</script>
<div id="divID">
    <div id="Title"></div>
    <div id="Text"></div>
</div>
```

**External.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

});

function pageLoad() {
    $("#divID").hide();

    $("#Description").hover(function () {
        $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
        $(this).css("color", "blue");
        $("#Title").text(testTitle);
        $("#Text").text(testText);
        $("#divID").show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).css("color", "rgb(80,80,80)");
        $("#divID").hide();
    });
}
```

**Result:** "#testText" and "#testTitle" content is not displayed.

jQuery.css styles and Triggers works.

What am i doing wrong ?

// EDIT - Source Page
**Page Source Code:**

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
         var testTitle = "Level";
         var testText = "Row
Another Row";
     </script>
```

Can this cause issue ?

Comment: Can you also share the asp.net output available in your browser by viewing the page source, so we than could view the actual html. I think the js in the html is malformed

Comment: There are no value associated with divID.

Comment: @rontornambe
Thank you, i meant #testTitle and #testText vaulues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an workaround using only asp to handle content, and jquery to display it.
So there is no more need to pass variables from asp to js anymore.

Comment: Please post your solution!